CDC cleanup job -- history
On SQL Server 2019, I enabled CDC on some tables about 2 days ago. The CDC cleanup job is scheduled to run every day and the retention period is 3 days.
When I checked the job history of the cleanup job, I found nothing there. I ran the job manually and by the next day I found that even the manual job I ran was no longer there.
How can I be sure that the cleanup job is running as it should, also could there be anything that is clearing the job history?
The database is also part of always-on availability group.
Please, help.


could there be anything that is clearing the job history?

Yes, the job history gets automatically cleared over time. You can tweak how much of job history is retained in SQL Server Agent properties.
Though those options are rather minimalistic.

Thanks for your response.
I noticed that this morning, it appeared the clean-up job ran but I can't find anything in the job history.
Two days ago, I found 2 records, and yesterday I found 1 record. However, today I found none. The concern i have here is that i want to make sure that the CDC cleanup job is running to avoid the CDC data growing out of proportion. How else can I monitor this aside right clicking and then doing view history.
